# CSS Fixed Header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to fix my header on the top. I've looked at other posts and am sure that I'm doing it right. This is the CSS for the header:

```
.header{
    width: 100%;
    position:fixed;
    top: 0px;
}
```

For some reason when I do this, the header disappears. Any ideas for why? And how should I change the code? 
FYI I'm using bootstrap and adding this into it.

Thanks a ton, Stefan

After seeing so answer I made so edits, but it disappeared on me again. The CSS I am using is:

```
position: fixed; 
width:960px;
```

Anymore help? Really appreciated.

Comment: edit `fixes` to `fixed`. and it may need `z-index`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple typo in your `position` - you want `fixed` not `fixes`.

```
.header{
     width: 100%;
     position:fixed;
     top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton didn't realized that. :)

Comment: @StefanWalzer-Goldfeld A little pro-tip: get used to using Developer Tools in your browser (Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer). You would have been able to navigate to your header element, and in the CSS Inspection panel, `position: fixes` would have been highlighted/noted as 'Incorrect Value'.

Comment: Developer tool in browser? Also, don't have it up on the web yet, so I could do that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is good. You may try to inspect the element using firebug addon and see any conflict there.You can also try to add height , if still not solve then you can take a look [sticky header](http://codeconvey.com/create-simple-pur-css-sticky-header/) article that explain  process of making it.

```
.header{
 width: 100%;
 position:fixed;
 top: 0px;
 height:50px;
}
```